# Do all UIVIewControllers come with a UINavigationController, UISearchDisplayController, etc?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I just noticed that UIViewController have properties like

```
self.navigationController
self.searchDisplayController
```

etc. Which confused me a bit. I did not define these in my xib file - but I notice I can access and use them and they will automatically show up in my view. What is the reason for having these instantiated for all view controllers?

What if I want to define and hook up my own via the xib file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those values are `nil` by default. They only return values if the view controller has been setup with the corresponding controller.

In other words, if the view controller has not been added to a nav controller then the `navigationController` property returns `nil`. Same for the `searchDisplayController`.